# I want to display multiplication table in java but only from 1 to 20

Tags: java, multiplication

My current java program displays multiplication table from zero to infinity.

- i want to limit that from 1 to 20 only...i want multiplication table output from 0 to 20 only.
- i.e. i dont want multiplication table of zero or any number greater than 20 as output.
- is it possible to do what i want using loops only
- if not loops then how
- i copied this problem and solution from hackerrank...
  Here is the code...

````java
import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.security.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
public class Solution {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    int N = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i) {
      System.out.println(N " x "(i 1)
        " = "(N * (i 1)));
    }
    bufferedReader.close();
  }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

most of your code is fine, you just need to add a condition to validate 1 to 20 number and also you need start your loop from 1 instead of 0, take a look at below code, this will resolve your issue

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    int N = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());
    if (N >= 1 && N <= 20) {
        for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(N + " x " + (i + 1) + " = " + (N * (i + 1)));
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Enter Numbers in between 1 to 20");
    }

    bufferedReader.close();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use an if statement before for loop

```
 if(N >0 && N<=20){
   for (int i=1; i<= 10; i++){

       System.out.println(N + " x " + (i) + " = " + (N *i));
   }
} else{  
    // Number should be greater than 0 and less than 21
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
for (int i=1; i <= 10; i++){
    int result = N*i;
    if (result >= 1 && result <= 20) {
        System.out.println(N + " x " + i + " = " + result);
    }
}
```

seems like the way to go... Did I misunderstand the question in some way? This seems fairly straightforward...

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
public class Solution {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

      try(BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))){
          //Let say we are getting the limit of the table number from console
          int endTableNumber = Integer.parseInt(bufferedReader.readLine().trim());
          
          //As per condition table number neither above 20 nor zero 
          if(endTableNumber <=0 || endTableNumber > 20) {
              System.err.println("Allowed Table printing limit is 1 to 20");
          }
          
          //setting offset table number as 1 as per condition
          int startTableNumber = 1;
       
          //outer for loop: table
          for (int i=startTableNumber; i<= endTableNumber; i++){
              System.out.println("Table : "+ i);
            //outer for loop: table's entry
              for(int j=1; j <= 20; j++ ) {
                  System.out.println(j + " x " + (i) + " = " + (j * (i)));
              }
              System.out.println("");
          }
      }

  }

}
```